# Moving Animated Menubar in Silverlight

Tags: animation, silverlight, menu

I have started UI Design in Silverlight I wanted to make a on mouse over moving menu bar as it is in this link: http://scr.templatemonster.com/34800/34855-silver.html

I am new to Silverlight animation.

Comment: I don't see anything at the link provided: Also, generally you'll be asked what you've tried first.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can go about making this work. If I understand the question correctly you want to make a visual element change when you scroll over the item. In the example from the link the photo looks to be surrounded with a border and when the mouse enters the border the border thickness is changed to give the effect. 
If you are handling UI display items in the code behind you can simply handle the event and change the border thickness with the mouseenter and mouseleave events.
If you are using view models (recommended) you can bind the thickness to a property on the view model and use the interaction library and event to command library from Galasoft to change the property value when those events occur. If you are unfamiliar with the MVVM pattern you will need to ensure your view models implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and your properties fire the event when changed.
Hope this helps.